# Best way for checking if a Id is repeated in javascript [performance]

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a list of repeated products with it's Ids, having a loop I want each product goes just once through that loop. I want to prevent that product going through the next times.

I want to know the best way of doing this:

1)

```
var hanSalido = {};
if(typeof(hanSalido[productGroup.getValue()]) == 'undefined'){
                            hanSalido[productGroup.getValue()] = true;
                        }else{
                            continue;
                        }
```

2)

```
var hanSalido = [];
if(hanSalido.indexOf(productGroup.getValue()) > -1){
    continue;
}else{
    hanSalido.push(productGroup.getValue());
}
```

3) 
Other way

Comment: 1) and 2) work with **different** types of source data: 1) generic `object`; 2) `array`. So what is exactly your **list**? object or array?

Comment: My object originally is a report from Google Adwords Scripts, but I think it doesn't care the source because I'am going trough all the data anyway. thanks

Comment: _it doesn't care the source.._ You **should care** about the data type since it specify the way you deal with the data

Comment: It's a row from Google Adwords API Report

Comment: Do we talk about the same thing? I've asked: what is `hanSalido` variable?

Comment: Sorry, it's empty... I use it just for keeping track of the passed products. Thanks! I want to know the best way for doing this, I want to know what should haSalido be.